# Why are dependently typed languages such as Agda used for proofs, if supercompilers for simpler typed languages can do the same?

Tags: type-theory, functional-programming, dependent-types, proof-assistants

Proof assistants such as Agda can be used to assert properties about programs, such as "the double of a number is even". Interestingly, [supercompilers can be used for the same purpose, creating typeless proofs](http://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/super-final.pdf). Even more interestingly, [macro tree transducers can, too](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.29.3629). My question is: what is the relationship between those? What does a dependently typed language have that makes it more powerful than other type systems as far as theorem proving goes, considering proofs can be done without types?

Answer (score 10):

I think you're confusing two things: dependently typed languages are convenient for **specifying** properties and **giving proofs** about functional programs. The techniques you mention are possible **decision procedures** for certain properties of functional programs.

The ability to specify program properties usually takes place within a *logic*. Dependent types are a kind of logic, when viewed through the [propositions-as-types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) lens. The nice thing about this logic is that it is naturally suited to talk about functional programs, which also can be used as a proof language. But there are other logics as well capable of doing this, and some are not based on dependent types.

Supercompilation type proofs are essentially a way to prove that two functions are *observationally equal* i.e. send identical inputs to outputs. But the fact that a supercompiled function $\mathrm{S}(f)$ is observationally equal to $f$ is not obvious: it has to be *proven*. Usually this is done with pen and paper, but of course Agda could be used for such a purpose.

Some things to note:

1. Agda is sufficiently powerful to prove (almost) all the program equivalences you could be interested in. The drawback is that you have to *supply* the proof yourself.
2. The things that can be proven automatically using SC or transducers are nice, but they only cover a tiny percent of what people want to prove about their functional programs. In particular, these techniques will fail with any slightly complex property (say, always returning a prime number) and even expressing the desired property may be hard (e.g. always returning a prime number).
3. There are a number of decision procedures for functional programs which are well-studied and offer similar or additional power as the techniques you mention. In particular [ACL2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL2) has been around for quite some time and is (I hear) quite powerful for these kinds of things.
4. *In theory*, we could integrate these kinds of procedures to help the user produce a proof in a system like Agda or Coq. There are a number of technical and social reasons for which this hasn't happened yet. There's still hope though! Note also that Coq has a fair number of automated techniques already.